# Simple issue with a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tcp

All I want to do is start a thread to listen for communication on a certain port.

I start this by having an 'ok' button on a jDialog. When 'ok' has been clicked, the jDialog should hide itself (*HostClientDialog.setVisible(false);*), which works when the thread start line isn't in there.

```
try {

            HostClientDialog.setVisible(false);

            // start a thread that listens for incoming messages
            new gameCycle().start();

} catch (Exception e) { }
```

The *new gameCycle().start();* line is calling the following code:

```
public class gameCycle extends Thread {

    //public gameCycle(){
      //  super();
    //}

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            ServerSocket connection = new ServerSocket(4242);

            // Wait for connection
            Socket s = connection.accept();

            // Socket input
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

            // for receiving moves
            while (true) {

                String message = "";

                message = in.readLine();

                if (message != null && !message.equals("")) {
                    // do something with message
                }

                sleep(100);

            } // end while

        } catch (Exception e) { }

    } // end run
} // end class
```

I understood the above code to be looping until a message is received, and then doing something with the message. But when you execute this code, the jDialog box is made again (instantly) and re-prompts the user to click ok. It won't let the user get past the jDialog box, it will just continually re-prompt them.

I'm fairly novice with threads (I haven't done much more than printing using multiple threads), so I feel like I might be me implementing it incorrectly. But I've looked around for examples, and they seem to be more or less what I have.

**EDIT (11/29/2010 at 1:30 AM EST)**

It seems that I don't quite have the idea of TCP communication down as well as I thought. My goal with the thread and subsequent while loop was as follows:

- In the background the program would
  be waiting for any messages sent its
  way
- If it it received a message it would update something on the GUI, and then go back to waiting for more messages

All the while allowing the user to be continually using the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the code you supplied, looks fine to me.

I would implement the possibility to cancel the whole thread instead of looping with while(true).
Use a boolean instead and make the boolean accessible for other threads. If you need help on that, come back at me.

I think the problem lies with the code we do NOT see here.
I'm partially interested in the code fragments surrounding the .start() call on your thread. What happens after that?

cheers

EDIT:

```
 public class Main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JDialog dia = new JDialog();
    JButton btn = new JButton("Foo");
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            dia.setVisible(false);
            Runnable t = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("foo");
                }
            };
            t.run();
        }
    });
    dia.getContentPane().add(btn);
    dia.setSize(500, 400);
    dia.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

This works perfectly for me - sorry but I can't reproduce the error like you stated in the comments. Consider giving more code please :)

EDIT #2:
Don't set any variables from within your thread directly. Instead make use of the observer-listener pattern. When there is a new message incoming, have the thread fire a propertyChangeEvent instead. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html

Maybe you should try and implement something more trivial .. go for a quick and easy chat first. http://www.ashishmyles.com/tutorials/tcpchat/index.html

When you have that down, think about your project ahead. Maybe reading on multithreading with swing might help? http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Threads/swing/

Comment: Nothing actually. I commented out everything around the area and reran the code, and I get the same result. So, the code I have up there is all that is getting executed.

Comment: When you debug through your code step-by-step, there must be some code following.. look for something that might instantiate a new instance of your jdialog or some code that sets the visibility to true again.

Comment: It must be doing something like that, but from stepping through it I can't see anything like that. It just keeps coming back to the new Thread declaration. If you declare a jDialog and have it call that code up there (even with an empty run statement), you'll get the same result as me. I just tested it that way.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect your comment as well as your latest edit in OP.

Comment: What you've said is 100% correct. I took out some stuff that I thought was inconsequential to shorten the code I was posting, and that's where the issue ended up being. I was creating an instance of the caller class so that inside of the thread I could call a function, which was just reinitializing itself and re-prompting the user.

Comment: Is there any way to call a method from inside a thread? The only way I could find without making an instance of the calling class first was to make the method being called from inside the thread static. But then all of the variables used in the method needed to be changed to static. It just started a domino effect.

Answer (score 1):

Looks OK but I'm suspicious of that empty catch block. Or maybe that method is being invoked again?

Also if message == null you must exit the reading loop and close the socket, and the sleep is pointless: readline() will block if no data. And initializing 'message' is also pointless when you're about to assign it in the very next line.

Comment: Noted. So should I put the Socket and BufferedReader declarations in the while loop so that they're remade every time?

Comment: Certainly not. No idea how you got that out of what I said. You can't do that in the case of the socket, and if you do it with the BufferedReader you will lose data.

Comment: I was unsure how the connection would remain intact if I closed the socket at the bottom of the while loop. If I close the socket near the bottom of the while loop, does the line in.readLine() reopen the connection?

Comment: What? You close the socket *and exit the reading loop* because readLine() returned null, which in turn is because the peer closed the connection. You wouldn't be trying to read another line in that circumstance. Not that readLine() would reopen the socket in any case, it would just throw an exception..

Comment: I made an edit to the main post that I hope will more clearly state what I thought it was doing/what I would like it to be doing.

Comment: Doesn't change anything I've said here, and doesn't implement it either.

Answer (score 1):

> I understood the above code to be looping until a message is received

Not quite. This line:

```
Socket s = connection.accept();
```

will block the execution thread until a connection is made. Are you sure that is happening? It might be that your program is simply sitting there waiting for a connection but none are being made (successfully anyway).

Maybe post some more info, like what the class requesting the connection looks like.

Comment: If my goal is to have a thread waiting for incoming information, and when it receives information, to pass it on, and then go back to waiting for information; how would I want to set up the connection?

Comment: @Ryan I think you understood me wrong. Your setup looks fine. I was just saying that your statement was wrong. The code does not loop until a message is received. It WAITS until a message is received and then loops. Show us what the code that REQUESTS the connection looks like. Maybe we can help then.

Comment: I'm currently working on that part. I was simply trying to get the 'server' portion running and for now, just have it sit there and expect a message.